# Couchbase, two user registering with same username but different datacenters?

Tags: database, cassandra, couchbase

Let's say I have two users, Alice in North America and Bob in Europe. Both want to register a new account with the same username, at the same time, on different datacenters. The datacenters are configured to replicate between each other using eventual consistency.

How can I make sure only one of them succeeds at registering the username? Keep in mind that the connection between the datacenters might even be offline at the time (worst case, but daily occurance on spotify's cassandra setup).

EDIT:
I do realize the key uniqueness is the big problem here. The thing is that I need all usernames to be unique. Imagine using twitter if you couldn't tag a specific person, but had to tag everyone with the same username.

Answer (score 2):

With any eventual consistency system, and particularly in the presence of a network partition, you essentially have two choices:

1. Accept collisions, and pick a winner later.
2. Ensure you never have a collision.

In the case of Couchbase:

For (1) that means letting two users register with the same address in both NA and EU, and then later picking one as the "winner" (when the network link is present - not a very desirable outcome for something like a user account. A slight variation on this would be something like @Robert's suggestion and putting them in a staging area (which means the account cannot be made "active" until the partition is resolved), and then telling the "winning" user they have successfully registered, and the "loser" that the name is taken and to try again.

For (2) this means making the users unique, even though they pick the same username - for example adding a `NA::` / `EU::` prefix to their username document. When they login the application would need some logic to try looking up both document variations - likely trying the prefix for the local region first. (This is essentially the same idea as "realms" or "servers" that many MMO games use).

There are variations of both of these, but ultimately given an [AP-type system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem) (which Couchbase across XDCR is) you've essentially chosen Availability & Partition-Tolerance over Consistancy, and hence need to reconcile that at the application layer.

Answer (score 1):

Put the user name registrations into a staging table until you can perform a replication to determine if the name already exists in one of the other data centers.

Answer (score 1):

You tagged Couchbase, so I will answer about that.

As long as the key for each object is different, you should be fine with Couchbase. It is the keys that would be unique and work great with XDCR. Another solution would be to have a concatenated key made up of the username and other values (company name, etc) if that suits your use case, again giving you a unique key for the object. Yet another would be to have a key/value in a JSON document that is the username.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me whether you're using Cassandra or Couchbase. 
As far as Cassandra is concerned, since version 2.0, you can use [Lightweight Transactions](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/lightweight-transactions-in-cassandra-2-0) which are created for the goal. A Serial Consistency has been created just to achieve what you need. In the above link you can read what follows:

> For example, suppose that I have an application that allows users to
>   register new accounts. 
> Without linearizable consistency, I have no way
>   to make sure I allow exactly one user to claim a given account — I
>   have a race condition analogous to two threads attempting to insert
>   into a [non-concurrent] Map: even if I check for existence before
>   performing the insert in one thread, I can’t guarantee that no other
>   thread inserts it after the check but before I do.

As far as the missing connection between two or more cluster its your choice how to handle it. If you can't guarantee the uniqueness at insert-time you can both refuse the registration or dealing with it, accepting and apologize later.

HTH, Carlo